# Divide an array element into consecutive sets and find the smallest sum

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Let's say i have an array:

 *the number is within the range 0-100

 *the array length is within the range 0-10

 *the size of each sets is within the range 0-3

```
int[] MyArray = {9,1,3,3,2,4,4,2,1,6}; //example
```

and i want to divide this array into consecutive sets like this between 2 or 3 elements

```
[9,1] or [1,3] or [9,1,3] etc.
```

the purpose of doing this is I want to sum this sets and find the smallest sum. How do I do this?

Comment: Find the smallest two elements. That is the correct result.

Comment: The question is unclear - what's random about this, are the elements continuous, and what exactly do you want? The smallest subset of n (distinct/continuous/..?) elements? Can numbers be negative?

Comment: smallest sum of what?

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 1):

For set of elements you can use **Two Dimensional Array** 
In 2D-array second dimensional use for your size of your set.

Algorithm :

1: Create 2D array.
2: store element using Index of first array

```
class A 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k=0;
    int a[] = {1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,2,4};
    int b[][] = new int[50][4];

    for(int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i+=3) 
    {
        for (int j=0 ; j<b[0].length ; i++ )
        {
            b[k][i] = a[i];

        }
        k++;
    }

    for(int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i+=3) 
    {
        for (int j=0 ; j<b[0].length ; j++ )
        {
            System.out.println(b[j][i]);                
        }
    }

  }
}
```

[Graphical Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdBAo.jpg)

Comment: If you can include the code along with your answer the OP might accept it as an "Answer".

Comment: I am trying to convert this concept in code but i got exception of arrayindexout of bound

Answer (score 0):

- Have a pointer that traverse from element 0 (current point).
- Calculate the previous sum of elements so far(ps).
- Add current element with the previous sum and see if this is lowest (as per your logic omit the biggest previous element).

Your question would be worth for writing an algorithm, if your array has negative elements.